# For creating tools, Bash, Perl or Python? Which should I invest my time in to?

Tags: python, tools, perl, bash-scripting

Having trouble choosing between the three, I would of course love to learn all three in the future, but right now I'm curious as to which language would be the most beneficial to me.

Also, I'm aware that different tools might be more useful in certain scenarios, in this case, I just want to learn the language that suits best for creating Ethical hacking tools, and which language would be the easiest to master?

Comment: As someone who used to use and love Perl: let it die. Learn python.

Comment: @ConorMancone I would love an explanation if you have the time, but either way, thanks for the answer pal!

Comment: What might be easy for you to master might be different from other people. It also depends on what you want to *do*. Short answer: pick one and you will learn lots that will transfer over to any other language.

Comment: @schroeder that's probably the kindest and most sensible advice I've gotten, thanks man, will keep that in mind :)